# Can someone give me their Nexus 5 sbin directory?

Tags: root-access, nexus-5

I'm in the process of trying to root my phone without the screen (dropped it in water). I went to copy the su binary to the `/system/sbin/` directory and left off the '/'. So now I just overwrote my sbin directory with the su binary.

Can someone post me their `/system/sbin/` directory so I can restore it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Depends how desperate you are for the files. So here is a way to get the files yourself incase nobody else loads up the actual files for you.

You will need to do all this on a Linux box of your choice. Best way to approach this is to download your image file from google

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerheadkrt16m

As you can see at the moment there are two builds for the Nexus 5

Once you download that file unzip that file until you find the img files. There will be one called system.img which will probably contain the files you need.

Unfortunately the img is compressed any you will need to uncompress that image first.

There is a thread over here that discusses this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1081239

Once you have the image that has been uncompressed you should be able to mount it on a loop back device

mount -o loop system.raw.img mnt <- Create the mnt directory first

Then that mounted directory should show you all the files